# checking for multiple nulls values in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to query for null value where it will appear when it fulfilled 2 conditions. One of the conditions is for column [date out] value being empty for 2 datatables the other condition is  [date in] empty for 1 only. The query i have use shows the data being multiplied.

```
SELECT [c1 barcode].*
FROM [c1 barcode], [c# barcode]
WHERE (     (([c# barcode].[Date out]) Is Null) 
        AND (([c1 barcode].[Date out]) Is Null)
      ) 
   OR ((([c1 barcode].[Date in]) Is Null));
```

[image: example]

Comment: The output looks like `FROM d2 LEFT JOIN d1 ON d1.workorder = d2.workorder WHERE d1.workorder IS NULL`. The relation between dates and nulls in source data and desured output is absolutely unclear...

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a relationship between the tables, to avoid duplicates. If it's the workorder, then:

```
SELECT [c1 barcode].*
FROM [c1 barcode] , [c# barcode] 
WHERE [c1 barcode].workorder = [c# barcode].workorder
AND (
(   (([c# barcode].[Date out]) Is Null) 
    AND (([c1 barcode].[Date out]) Is Null)
    ) 
    OR ((([c1 barcode].[Date in]) Is Null))
)
```

or rather, more idiomatically :

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM [c1 barcode] c1 INNER JOIN [c# barcode] c2 ON c1.workorder = c2.workorder
WHERE (c2.[Date out] Is Null AND c1.[Date out] Is Null)
      OR c1.[Date in] Is Null
```